# Can I restore a /Home from a 32 bit 11.10 backup to a new 64 bit 12.04 install

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.04

When I install a 64 bit 12.04, can I safely restore /Home from an 32 bit 11.10 backup of /Home. I've been using the the Backup facility in the 11.10 System Settings and am hoping that the same facility in 12.04 will be compatible with the backup made with 11.10. I normally use the upgrade vs new install approach for new Ubuntu releases. Up to now I've stuck with 32 bit versions of Ubuntu but would like to benefit from the advantages that may be offered by going to 64 bit. Restoring from backup would be much more convenient than separating all my application created data from the various configuration files created by the applications which I've no doubt would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine in most regards. The configuration files stored in your `~/` directory are mostly bit-width independent. They generally store settings related to programs that don't deal with that level of detail.

If you have compiled any programs of your own under `~/` then you'd have to recompile them for 64-bit (if you wanted to use larger bit-width, that is)